# Laravel pass optional variable to view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable that may or may not be populated in my controller.

For example.

```
public function controllerMethod() {
   if($condition) {
     $var = "value";
   }

   return view("viewname",[
    "var" => $var
    ]
}
```

This gives an undefined variable error.

How do I pass this only if it exists?

I know that I could do another if statement, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: `"var" => $condition ? 'value' : false`

Comment: can you share the view code ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send parameters conditionally, you just have to add them to the `array` you send if it meets the condition:

```
public function controllerMethod() {
   $parameters = [];

   if ($condition) {
     $parameters['var'] = "value";
   }

   return view("viewname",$parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

`Controller`

```
public function controllerMethod() 
{
   if($condition) {
     $var = "value";
   }

   return view("viewname", compact('var', 'abc')); // you can pass multiple variables
}
```

`Blade File`

```
@if(isset($var))
  //if condition
@else
  //else condition
@endif
```

OR

`Controller`

```
public function controllerMethod() 
{
   $var = null;
   if($condition)  {
     $var = "value";
   }

   return view("viewname", compact('var')); // you can pass multiple variables
}
```

`Blade File`

```
@if($var)
  //if condition
@else
  //else condition
@endif
```

Comment: I love the first method. Btw in the view, instead of ` @if(isset($var) //code @else //other code @endif ` we can do ` @isset($var) //code @else //another code @endisset `

Answer (score 0):

It depends on choice what you want to show in view once condition is true
inside your controller. You can handle it in both controller and view. 
Code below will show "Result not found" if condition is wrong in controller and undefined error will not occur.

```
public function controllerMethod() {
   if($condition) 
   {
     $var = "value";
   }
   else
   {
     $var = "Result not found";
   }
   return view("viewname",
    [
      "var" => $var
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```php
if (isset($var)) {
    return view("viewname", [
        "var" => $var
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function controllerMethod() {

    $var="";
   if($condition) {
     $var = "value";
   }

   return view("viewname",[
    "var" => $var
    ]
}
```

On UI, have a check like this:

```
if (!empty($var)){
  //whatever you wanna do with your $var
}
```